# How To Show Total Cart Order Amount In Desctiption Payment Method in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to add a HTML Description to a Payment Method in WooCommerce.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_description', 'rudr_change_payment_gateway_description', 25, 2 );
function rudr_change_payment_gateway_description( $description, $gateway_id ) {
    if( 'pec_gateway_check' === $gateway_id ) {
        ?>

    <div class="mcpec-text">
      <span class="mcp-item">مبلغ پرداختی آنلاین شما:<span class="mcp-item-inner"> <!--1 total order * 35% --> </span></span>
      <span class="mcp-item">مبلغ چک صیادی:<span class="mcp-item-inner"> <!--2 total order * 65% --> </span></span>
      <span class="mcp-item">تاریخ چک صیادی:<span class="mcp-item-inner"> <!--3 The date is 40 days later --> </span></span>
    </div>

    <?php
         $description = '';
    }
    return $description;
}
```

I want to display the total shopping cart in this description as below:

1- total order * 35% = amount+$  (example= 35,000$)

2- total order * 65% = amount+$  (example= 65,000$)

3- The date is 40 days later = today+40 days later (example= 2022/10/16)

Comment: Does your current code put the html in the proper place and you just need the calculation done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_gateway_description', 'rudr_change_payment_gateway_description', 25, 2 );
function rudr_change_payment_gateway_description( $description, $gateway_id ) {
    if( 'pec_gateway_check' === $gateway_id ) {
        global $woocommerce;
        $carttotal = $woocommerce->cart->total;
        
        
        ?>

    <div class="mcpec-text">
        <span class="mcp-item">مبلغ پرداختی آنلاین شما:<span class="mcp-item-inner"> <?php echo "35% is: " . number_format($carttotal*0.35, 2) . "$"; ?> </span></span>
      <span class="mcp-item">مبلغ چک صیادی:<span class="mcp-item-inner"> <?php echo "65% is: " .  number_format($carttotal*0.65, 2) . "$"; ?> </span></span>
        <span class="mcp-item">تاریخ چک صیادی:<span class="mcp-item-inner"> <?php echo "40 days later is: " .  date('Y/m/d', strtotime("+40 days")); ?> </span></span>
    </div>

    <?php
         $description = '';
    }
    return $description;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to separate the numbers into 3 digits?

Comment: Which numbers do you want to separate? the dollar amount or the dates or something else?

Comment: the dollar amount, ( example= 2,334,000 $ )

Comment: @omidchahardoli I have updated my answer, please use the updated code.